# TypeError: Cannot read property state of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to get the data out of state and apply the map function on it. I keep getting the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'financials' of null.

axios gets the following object, {symbol: "AAPL", financials: Array(4)}, thats why i'm using this.state.financials.financials

```
class Fundamentals extends Component {
  state = {
    financials: null,
    headers: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMOunt");
    await axios
      .get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual")
      .then(res => {
        const financials = res.data;
        this.setState({ financials });
        console.log(financials);
      });

    console.log("componentDidMount finished setting the data for the table");
  }

  render() {
    // const headers = this.getHeaders1();
    return (
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            {this.state.financials.financials.map(items => items)} <-- i want to get the data out of state and later put it into a table. 
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you put financials twice in {this.state.financials.financials.map(items => items)}

Comment: sorry, i should of clarified that axios's data contains an object with another financials nested within it.

https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because React tries to render before your API call completes, in which case `this.state.financials` still has its initial `null` value assigned to it.

Change the default value of financials as mentioned below

```
state = {
    financials: { financials: [] },
    headers: null
};
```

So the final code looks something like

```
class Fundamentals extends Component {
  state = {
    financials: { financials: [] },
    headers: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMOunt");
    await axios
      .get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual")
      .then(res => {
         const financials = res.data;
         this.setState({ financials });
         console.log(financials);
      });

      console.log("componentDidMount finished setting the data for the table");
   }

   render() {
     // const headers = this.getHeaders1();
     return (
       <GridContainer>
         <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
           <Card>
             {this.state.financials.financials.map(items => items)} <-- i want to get the data out of state and later put it into a table. 
           </Card>
         </GridItem>
       </GridContainer>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time the component renders, `this.state.financials` is `null`, because you are initializing it with `null`:

```
state = {
  financials: null,
  headers: null
};
```

And that's why you are getting that error. Here is a simple example that replicates the error:

```js
var state = {
  financials: null,
};

state.financials.financials.map(() => {});
```

You need to check in your render method whether the value is set, and do nothing if it isn't:

```
render() {
  // const headers = this.getHeaders1();
  if (!this.state.financials) {
    return null; // or some message that the data is loading
  }

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Card>
          {this.state.financials.financials.map(items => items)} <-- i want to get the data out of state and later put it into a table. 
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you could initialize it with `{financials: []}` instead:

```
state = {
  financials: {financials: []},
  headers: null
};
```

Then your existing code inside `render` should "work" (see below).

---

But that alone likely won't make your component work. You also need to actually convert the entries in `this.state.financials.financials` to something that React can render. Here is an example that pulls out the date:

```
this.state.financials.financials.map(item => item.reportDate)
```

Adjust this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check before you actually render the data.

```js
class Fundamentals extends Component {
  state = {
    financials: null,
    headers: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMOunt");
    await axios
      .get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/financials?period=annual")
      .then(res => {
        const financials = res.data;
        this.setState({ financials });
        console.log(financials);
      });

    console.log("componentDidMount finished setting the data for the table");
  }

  render() {
    const { financials: { financials} } = this.state;

    if(!financials || (financials && !financials.length) {
      return (
        <LoaderComponent />
      )
    }

    return (
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            {financials.map(items => items)} <-- i want to get the data out of state and later put it into a table. 
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    );
  }
}
```